# How to use trained Neural Network in Matlab for classification in a real system

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I have trained Feed Forward NN using Matlab Neural Network Toolbox on a dataset containing speech features and accelerometer measurements. Targetset contains two target classes for dataset: 0 and 1. The training, validation and performance are all fine and I have generated code for this network.

Now I need to use this neural network in real-time to recognize pattern when occur and generate 0 or 1 when I test a new dataset against previously trained NN. But when I issue a command:

```
   c = sim(net, j)
```

Where "j" is a new dataset[24x11]; instead 0 or 1 i get this as an output (I assume I get percent of correct classification but there is no classification result itself):

```
c =

  Columns 1 through 9

    0.6274    0.6248    0.9993    0.9991    0.9994    0.9999    0.9998    0.9934    0.9996

  Columns 10 through 11

    0.9966    0.9963
```

So is there any command or a way that I can actually see classification results? Any help highly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no matlab user, but from a logical point of view, you are missing an important point:

The input to a Neural Network is a single vector, you are passing a matrix. Thus matlab thinks that you want to classify a bunch of vectors (11 in your case). So the vector that you get is the output activation for every of these 11 vectors.

The output activation is a value between 0 and 1 (I guess you are using the sigmoid), so this is perfectly normal. Your job is to get a threshold that fits your data best. You can get this threshold with cross validation on your training/test data or by just choosing one (0.5?) and see if the results are "good" and modify if needed.

Comment: Hi, even if I try with single vector I get the same output. I have already done everything I needed with classifier, I don't want to change it further(Yes I have used sigmoid). The NN is trained with targets containing 0 and 1; so the output of the classification should be 0 or 1 (e.g. if I done this same with Iris example, classier should give me specie1 or specie2), I don't need anything else. If I missed something please correct me (are you trying to say for these numbers I get: if something is closer to 0 then it is first class, or if it is closer to 1 than it is second class?), Thanks

Comment: @supermus the net learns some approx. function to your input. The output of the function is usually not a straight one or zero, but something in between. So the interpretation of the output (choosing the threshold) must be done by your logic based on some metric or gut feeling. Do you have more documentation for the `sim` method? Are you sure that you just provided a single vector?

Comment: When I provide single vector I get one number as an output, but I was confused by the number meaning itself. I don't have any documentation on sim :/

Comment: @supermus ah okay, because you wrote `even if I try with single vector I get the same output`.

Comment: Yes, the same 0 point something for me until yesterday unknown value :) cheers

Answer (score 2):

NNs normally convert their output to a value within (0,1) using for example the logistic function. It's not a percentage or probability, just a relative measure of certainty. In any case this means is that you have to manually use a threshold (such as 0.5) to discriminate the two classes. Which threshold is best is tough to find because you must select the optimum trade off between precision and recall.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut Thank you very much guys! Even in this form the output is perfect for me as I can use it in my project! Don't know which answer to accept :)